# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9999/hello/sali' from origin 'http://localhost:8090'

Tags: javascript, nginx, axios, quasar

I am trying to enable CORS wildcard on NGINX as the following:

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  auto;
error_log         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log";
pid               "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/nginx.pid";

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format    main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
  '"$request" $status  $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log    "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log";
  add_header    X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

  client_body_temp_path  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body" 1 2;
  proxy_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/proxy" 1 2;
  fastcgi_temp_path      "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/fastcgi" 1 2;
  scgi_temp_path         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/scgi" 1 2;
  uwsgi_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/uwsgi" 1 2;

  sendfile           on;
  tcp_nopush         on;
  tcp_nodelay        off;
  gzip               on;
  gzip_http_version  1.0;
  gzip_comp_level    2;
  gzip_proxied       any;
  gzip_types         text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  ssl_protocols      TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  client_max_body_size 80M;
  server_tokens off;
  include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/*.conf";

  # HTTP Server
  server {
    # port to listen on. Can also be set to an IP:PORT
    listen  8080;

    location / {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }

    location /status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log   off;
      allow 127.0.0.1;
      deny all;
    }
  }
}
```

When I trigger a request to the URL `http://localhost:9999/hello/sali` with the following method:

```
methods: {
  load_user(event) {

    console.log(this.$kc)

    const config = {
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$kc.token}`}
    };

    this.$axios.get('http://localhost:9999/hello/sali', config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("errro")
      })
  },
```

Then it shows me in the javascript console:

[image]

Looking at the Network section on Chromium:
[image]

you can see, that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to `*`

What am I doing wrong?

Hint: I am using **NGINX Bitami**.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to `*` from the place where you try to make the call from. It needs to be on the location where you get the call. As you see the 'sali' request are all red.

Comment: @Tim567 no, actually the header is present on all responses. `/` matches every URI (as long as no other one matches, as that takes predescendence)

Comment: Are you sure that whoever answer the requests (I have no idea what bitnami is) also answers preflight requests with an OPTIONS method?

Comment: @JonasWilms Oh, didn't know that, Thanks!

Comment: @JonasWilms Why does it need preflight requests with an OPTIONS method?